# Linq Method error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to write a Linq method which i will call using ajax. I have the following error i dont know how to solve it?

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<ChillZARdev.Contents.DesignProfile.SearchResults>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'  D:\LetsWork0\ChillZARdev\ChillZARdev\Contents\Home.aspx.cs

The error is highlighted on the    `return lsSearchResults;`

```
 public static List<SearchResults> lsSearchResults = new List<SearchResults>();

 public static DBRelationalDataContext myDB = new DBRelationalDataContext();  public class SearchResults
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public SearchResults(string name, string surname)
        {
            Name = name;
            Surname = surname;

        }

    }

 [WebMethod] 

 Public static List<string> QuerySearch()
 {

        var found = (from User in myDB.Memberships
                     where User.Name.ToLower().Contains(RecordSearch) ||
                     User.Surname.ToLower().Contains(RecordSearch) ||

                     (User.Name + " " + User.Surname).ToLower().Contains(RecordSearch) ||
                     (User.Surname + " " + User.Surname).ToLower().Contains(RecordSearch)

                     select new SearchResults(User.Name, User.Surname)).ToList();

        //// validates items in search query if Exist
        if (!ChillZARdev.App_Code.Utilities.IsEmpty(found))
        {
            //  List<string> userRecord = new List<string>();
            List<SearchResults> lsSearchResults = new List<SearchResults>();
            foreach (var user in found)
            {

                //  userRecord.Add(user.Name );
                lsSearchResults.Add(new SearchResults(user.Name, user.Surname));
            }
            //Repeater1.EnableViewState = true;



            return lsSearchResults; // This is where the errror is highlighted

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling the compiler you will be returning a List of Strings, but are infact returning a List of `SearchResults`. The compiler doesn't know how to convert the List of `SearchResults` to a list of 'Strings'.

Change it from

```
public static List<string> QuerySearch()
```

To

```
public static List<SearchResults> QuerySearch()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return `List<SearchResults>` when the web method expects `List<string>`, you need to make sure you return `List<string>` e.g.

```
public class SearchResults
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public SearchResults(string name, string surname)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Surname);
    }
}

...
[WebMethod] 
Public static List<string> QuerySearch()
{
    ...
    return lsSearchResults.Select(i => i.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method return type is `List<string>` but you return `List<SearchResults>`, this is not allowed in C#

if you wanted return a list of names just do:

```
return lsSearchResults.Select(l => l.Name).ToList();
```

List of surnames will be:

```
return lsSearchResults.Select(l => l.SurName).ToList();
```

Or change method return type to `List<SearchResults>`

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `lsSearchResults` which is of type `SearchResults` but the method is expecting a `List<string>` to be returned.

You can change the return type to be `SearchResults` like this:

```
public static List<SearchResults> QuerySearch() {

}
```

Or return a `List<string>`

```
return lsSearchResults.Select(n => n.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
public static List<string> QuerySearch()
{
}
```

needs to return a `List<string>` and you are returning a `List<SearchResults>`.

Either change the return type to match what you are returning or visa versa.

So

```
public static List<string> QuerySearch()
{
    return new List<string>();
}
```

or

```
public static List<SearchResults> QuerySearch()
{
    return new List<SearchResults>();
}
```

Note, the method return type and the type you return in the method body must match.